# Как в Edit показать полупрозрачный текст который при введении текста исчезнет?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, edit

Сделал код но что-то не работает, помогите пожалуйста

```
unit Unit9;
interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, DB, ADODB, Grids, DBGrids, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm9 = class(TForm)
    qry1: TADOQuery;
    dbgrd1: TDBGrid;
    ds1: TDataSource;
    edt1: TEdit;
    pnl1: TPanel;
    procedure dbgrd1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure edt1Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form9: TForm9;

const
  EM_SETCUEBANNER = $1501;

implementation
uses Unit2;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm9.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Banner: String;
  buf: array [0..$ff] of Char;
begin
  Banner := UTF8Encode('Введите логин');
  Utf8ToUnicode(PWideChar(@buf), PAnsiChar(Banner), Length(Banner));
  SendMessage(edt1.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 0, Integer(@buf));
end;

end.
```

> например как на сайтах в edt написано "Логин" но при написании оно не
>   отображается

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53137010/how-to-implement-text-box-with-gray-text-hint/53151468#53151468

Comment: Напишите серым цветом в начале (в onformshow событие можно проверить пусто ли значение), а после событий OnEnter уберите текст и поменяйте цвет на черный

Comment: В Delphi 7 я делал так: `SendMessage(FEditBox, EM_SETCUEBANNER, WPARAM(TRUE), LPARAM(WideString(тут [ansi-]string переменная)));`

Answer (score 1):

Можно же просто указать значение Text, изменить Font.Color на серый, при попытке ввода удалять "placeholder" и делать Font.Color чёрного цвета. Может решение конечно не слишком элегантное, но тем не менее.

Answer (score -2):

Это называется placeholder, если вы работаете с визуальным редактором интерфейса, то такой метод (или похожий, гуглите placeholder + "ваш язык программирования") должен быть реализован по умолчанию. То, что вы привели в пример реализовано, именно, с помощью атрибута placeholder (placeholder = "Логин") в html разметке страницы.

Для Delphi можно использовать TEdit.TextHint. Подсказка или сообщение, которое будет отображаться, когда свойство Text пусто

Comment: Вопрос ведь про делфи, верно? Атрибут plaseholder есть в делфи? Вы точно уверены?

Comment: Можно использовать TEdit.TextHint. Подсказка или сообщение, которое будет отображаться, когда свойство Text пусто.

Comment: Юрий, TEdit.TextHint такого нету в Delphi.

Comment: @delphi обновите версию Делфи. В конце концов, есть бесплатная Community Edition (действует 1 год с последующим бесплатным продлением). В Делфи 7 (полагаю, Вы ее используете) такого свойства действительно нет.